# How to add new key-value pair in each object of JSONB Array- PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, postgresql-14

I have a table **master_data_approval_table** in my postgres DB having field **approval_value** (type Jsonb) which contains below JSON structure:

```
[{
        "name": "abc",
        "email": "abc.pqr@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "name": "xyz",
        "email": "xyz.pqr@gmail.com"
    }
]
```

Now we want to add one more key-value pair i.e. **"comment": null** in each object of the array like the below one:

```
[{
        "name": "abc",
        "email": "abc.pqr@gmail.com",
        "comment": null
    },
    {
        "name": "xyz",
        "email": "xyz.pqr@gmail.com",
        "comment": null
    }
]
```

In more to that we need to do this for all the records of the table.
I have tried different existing answers and queries but no help so please somebody guide me on how to write a query in PostgreSQL for the above scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unnest the JSON array with `jsonb_array_elements()`, use `||` to modify each object to add the new key/value, and finally aggregate back with `jsonb_agg()`, with respect to the original ordering:

```
select t.approval_value, e.new_approval_value
from master_data_approval_table t
cross join lateral (
    select jsonb_agg( e.elt || '{"comment": null}' order by e.seq) new_approval_value
    from jsonb_array_elements(t.approval_value) with ordinality as e(elt, seq)
) e
```

| approval_value | new_approval_value |
| --- | --- |
| [ { "name": "abc", "email": "abc.pqr@gmail.com" }, { "name": "xyz", "email": "xyz.pqr@gmail.com" } ] | [ { "name": "abc", "email": "abc.pqr@gmail.com", "comment": null }, { "name": "xyz", "email": "xyz.pqr@gmail.com", "comment": null } ] |

If you wanted to actually modify the values in the column, you would `update`:

```
update master_data_approval_table t
set approval_value = (
    select jsonb_agg( e.elt || '{"comment": null}' order by e.seq) new_approval_value
    from jsonb_array_elements(t.approval_value) with ordinality as e(elt, seq)
)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jb7W_9k0)

Comment: Thanks @GMB you saved my day...I don't think I would be able to construct that query in a very short time. Big thanks to you.